# How to open google sign in pop up with different clint_id s?

Tags: angular, google-apps-script, google-oauth, google-api-js-client

How can I open google sign in pop up with different clicnt_id s in one project? I want to have 2 different logins for mail and calendar. That's why I need 2 different client ids, but google make init only once, and the second doesn't work.

I have tried to call `gapi.auth2.init` twice, but second pop up doesn't open. Also I've tried with `gapi.auth2.authorize`.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code not an image of your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use angular environments

try to put a part of your code to see if i can help you a little more

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want two different client id's.  Client ids just denote your application to google. If you have two different client ids when you go to verify the application they are without a doubt going to make you remove one.

I question why you would want two different logins, but the solution would be to use two different users.